# Is Android lollipop's Job scheduler cleared jobs on device restart like alarm manager ?

Tags: android

### Is Android lollipop's Job scheduler cleared jobs on device restart like alarm manager ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it persists across reboots - which is considered as an improvement.

Comment: Is there any official document which tells this ?

Comment: I got it from @commonsware (user:115145), commonsware.com/presos/droidconUK2014-Volta.pdf